# Is there any method for C language to control length of characters by using a variable?

Tags: c, string, variables

Here is my code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    printf("%220s\n", "Hello, beautiful world!");
    printf("%232s\n", "Hello, beautiful world!");
    printf("%333s\n", "Hello, beautiful world!");
    printf("%444s\n", "Hello, beautiful world!");
    printf("%555s\n", "Hello, beautiful world!");

    return 0;
}
```

It takes a lot of typing and may be full of mistakes.

I am thinking of using a variable to control how many spaces the string can take up.

The following code

```
 #include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{

    int a[5] = {220, 232, 333, 444, 555};

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        printf("%%ds\n", a[i], "Hello, beautiful world!");

    return 0;
}
```

does not seem to work I expected.

Where did I do wrong?

Is there any method for C language to control length of characters by using a variable ?

Comment: `printf(“%*s\n”, a[i], “…”);`

Comment: Jonathan Leffler , thanks. It works. What's that method called?

Comment: Not sure; if there’s a name, it might be in the manual.  I’m on a plane w/o access to a manual.

Comment: The C standard does not give it a name. It is described in C 2011 7.21.6.1 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the * specifier to specify the minimum field width. For information please read the Format of the format string section on the [man page for printf](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html)

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int a[5] = {220, 232, 333, 444, 555};

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        printf("%*s\n", a[i], "Hello, beautiful world!");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: For C questions, it is preferable to refer to the C standard rather than to Linux manual pages.

Comment: The C standard is not publicly available on the net, only the final draft ([n1570 for C11](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html), [n1256 for previous C99](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c99/n1256.html)) is. The Linux man-pages project pages are actively maintained, and include a *Conforming to* section that does describe which standards each feature is defined in; GNU and Linux specifics are clearly marked. Therefore, I *slightly* disagree with @EricPostpischil: We can link to a draft of the standard (theory), or man-pages (practice). I say it is preferable to link to *both*.

Comment: @NominalAnimal: Linux manual pages may document which specifications they conform to, but that is insufficient. X conforms to Y if the set of behaviors of X is a subset of the set of behaviors permitted by Y. But X does not reveal Y−X, the set of behaviors permitted by Y but not exhibited by X. A person who learns “C does X” from a Linux man page could go on to write some code they expect to work in C only for it to fail on implementations that differ from Linux but conform to the C standard. The proper reference for the C standard is the C standard.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Perhaps, but the fact remains, we only have access to the final draft, not the C standard proper. You may enjoy [tag:language-lawyer]ism, but the rest of us must use multiple sources to find the golden path between theory and practice. Note that I linked to the web-accessible copies to the standards drafts above; I'm not pushing for any one source, but for using *multiple reference sources*.

Comment: @NominalAnimal: As [M.M](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1505939/m-m) notes, citing the draft is acceptable on Stack Overflow. But it is not true that the public does not have access to the standard. Yes, the current version [costs CHF 198 (USD 200)](https://www.iso.org/standard/74528.html). That is not a large expense to anybody using C to earn income or for anybody who relies on the standard or expects their users to rely on the software they produce with it. If students continue using the draft until they become employed, that is fine. If one is in another situation and cannot afford it…

Comment: … they could talk to their public library or school library about acquiring a copy.